# Is it possible to declare a dependency which tracks the version of a transitive dependency?

Tags: npm

I've run into a situation where I need to access a transitive dependency in a stable way. In other words, I'd like to declare a dependency whose version is "whatever library Foo is already using".

Specifically, I'm setting up an Eleventy site and want to use `markdown-it-anchor` with it. Both libraries involve slugifying text, for which `markdown-it-anchor` allows you to specify a custom function. To keep everything consistent, I want to tell `markdown-it-anchor` to use the same slugifying function as Eleventy. Eleventy doesn't export its slugifying function, but it's just using `@sindresorhus/slugify`, so I can import that directly.

The problem came in when I added a direct dependency on `@sindresorhus/slugify` — I added a dependency with a splat version, on the assumption that npm would simply resolve it to the version of `@sindresorhus/slugify` which was already present in `node_modules/`. Instead, it resolved to the latest version. I tried playing around with editing `package.json` and even `package-lock.json` manually, but npm is very firm about installing Eleventy's version of `@sindresorhus/slugify` where I can't reach it and not installing the same version for my own use unless I duplicate the version specifier in my `package.json`.

What I want is to be able to freely update Eleventy in the future and have reasonable confidence that `markdown-it-anchor` will continue to be passed the correct version of `@sindresorhus/slugify` without having to manually verify each time that Eleventy hasn't bumped their dependency. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I *kind of* got this to work. I say "kind of" because I'm depending on the splat version (`"*"`) of my transitive dependency, which is pretty fragile. Getting it to work at all was pretty ugly, too, so there are multiple ways in which this isn't a "proper" solution.

1. Opened up `package-lock.json` and looked at the transitive dependency's dependencies (and transitive dependencies). Fortunately, for `@sindresorhus/slugify`, this isn't too bad.
2. Rearranged `node_modules/` to move the transitive dependency to the top level (where my package can find it), and all of *it's* dependencies to where *it* can find them, without introducing new version conflicts. Again, in my case, this wasn't too bad.
3. Edited both `package-lock.json` and `node_modules/.package-lock.json` to reflect the moved packages' new locations.
4. Ran `npm ci` both to verify that I hadn't made any terrible mistakes and to make sure `package-lock.json` and `node_modules/.package-lock.json` were formatted the way it liked. (The only change it made was to reorder the packages to keep their directories sorted.)
5. Manually added a dependency on the (now formerly) transitive dependency with a splat version.
6. Ran `npm install` and verified that it didn't actually install or rearrange anything.

After all that, `@sindresorhus/slugify` works as expected when used directly from my site's build. There are a couple of serious caveats, though:

- I'm not sure what npm's behavior will be if/when Eleventy updates its dependency on `@sindresorhus/slugify`. It may well simply update the latter where it's already located, in which everything will be fine. Otherwise, it probably won't.
- I'm also not sure what npm's behavior will be if/when `@sindresorhus/slugify` gets added as a dependency anywhere else. It may well leave the existing version where it is and install new, conflicting versions under the `…/node_modules/` folder of whatever packages require them, in which case everything will be fine. Otherwise, it probably won't.

In other words, I discovered a way to put a fair amount of effort into creating a situation which *seems* to work, but may not actually do what I originally wanted.